# How to prove single point sets are Borel sets (with the given definition of a Borel set).

Tags: measure-theory

A book I'm reading defines Borel sets as :

> For E we choose the set of all bounded semiclosed intervals of the form
>
> $[a,b) \equiv \{x : a \leq x < b \} $
>
> The *Borel sets* on the real line are the sets contained in the $\sigma$-ring $\Re(E)$ generated by this class E.

How can one prove using this definition that single point sets (e.g. $\{a\}$) are Borel sets? I understand it's possible to express a single point set $\{a\}$ as an infinite intersection of intervals $\bigcap_{n} (a - 1/n, a+ 1/n)$, but how do we work this into the above definition (which seems to be dealing with infinite unions of intervals of the form $[a,b)$ )?

Comment: you could use de morgans laws

Comment: Instead of taking symmetric open intervals, take half-open intervals $[a, a + 1/n)$.

Comment: Ok, so then would this be correct? : By the definition of a σ-ring all countable unions of E are in E. Now if  {a} is the countably infinite intersection of [a, a+1/n) intervals, then by De Morgan's law {a} is also the complement of the countably infinite union of complements of [a, a+1/n). Since each of these complements are (I presume) in E, their infinite union is also, and so is its complement.

Comment: Alternatively, you could prove that an open inverval is an infinite union of semiclosed intervals, and then use what you know about a single point sets as an infinite intersection of open intervals. (This is like the way a mathematician boils water in the old joke.)

Answer (score 1):

all the time, I have seen proofs that show that points belong to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra because they are a countable intersection of closed sets. That is,

$$\left\{a \right\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [a,a + 1/n] \quad \text{ or } \quad  \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [a - 1/n,a] \quad \text{ or }  \quad\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [a - 1/n,a + 1/n] $$

The above equations hold because {a} is the only subset of every set in the sequences considered.

Now, closed intervals can be generated from the complement of a union of open intervals, and open intervals from the union of left semi-closed intervals (the ones your book mentions). Formally,

$$ [a,b] =  \left\{(-\infty,a) \cup (b,\infty) \right\}^c$$

$$ (a,b) =  \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [a + 1/n,b)$$

$$ (a,\infty) =  \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (a ,b + n) $$

$$ (-\infty,b) =  \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (a - n ,b)$$

Therefore, singletons being the countable intersection of elements of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra are also part of it themselves.